# Disable adding github token in requirements.txt from pip-compile

Tags: python, pip, token, pip-tools

I have a file requirements.in with below context:

```
.
.
.
git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/company/some-lib-name.git@v1.4.0
pyzipcode3==2.2
pytz==2019.3
timezonefinder==4.1.0
sqlalchemy==1.2.18
```

Private lib is downloaded from company's github repo over token.

My problem is that `${GITHUB_TOKEN}` is replaced with real token and stored in requirements.txt when I call `pip-compile`, how to remove token from requirements.txt?

My output looks like for requirements.txt:

```
some-lib-name @ git+https://ghp_MY_REAL_GITHUB_KEY@github.com/company/some-lib-name.git@v1.4.0
    # via -r requirements.in
s3transfer==0.2.1
    # via boto3
```

I am using python 3.
How to get requirements.txt without real github_token in this file?
Can I get format as in requirements.in (git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/company/some-lib-name.git@v1.4.0)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `pip-tools` expands all environments in `requirements.in` while compiles `requirements.txt`. There is an open issue, see [#966](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/966). See also [this comment](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/966#issuecomment-545583824) for suggested workarounds.